# Windows Phone 8.1: How to get a ListView inside a Hub

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8

So I have XAML code for a Hub control, and of course each section of a Hub contains a DataTemplate block. I would like to put my ListView (which has a DataTemplate block of its own) inside one of the Hub sections, but when I try I get the following error:

> Duplication assignment to the 'Template' property of the 'DataTemplate' object

What is the issue exactly, and how do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the `ListView` as a direct child to the `HubSection`, then the `DataTemplate` is being assigned to both (which it cannot do). If you put the `ListView` inside of the `DataTemplate` of the the `HubSection`, it should work.

So you can try:

```
<HubSection...>
    <DataTemplate...>
        <ListView....>
             <!--List view stuff (including another <DataTemplate>-->
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried both ways: putting the Listview Inside the Hub's DataTemplate as well as outside of it. Both of them produced the same error.

Comment: Huh, I just messed around more and realized that besides DataTemplate being underlined, <Grid/> was as well. When I deleted grid, everything started working okay.

Thank you!